# Grails domain mapping of legacy tables that share same primary key name

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, one-to-one, grails-domain-class

The legacy database has two tables that use the same column name as the primary key. For example:

user:
user_id int
name string

user_profile:
user_id int
visit_count int

I would like to create a bidirectional one-to-one relationship. i.e.

```
class User {
    String name
    UserProfile userProfile
    static mapping = {
        id column: 'user_id'
    }
}

class UserProfile {
    Integer visitCount
    User user
    static mapping = {
        id column: 'user_id'
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to reference 'user.userProfile.visitCount' or 'userProfile.user.name'.

I have tried many combinations of direct references and relationship discriptors, 'hasOne', 'belongsTo', etc.  I would think this is simple but cannot find the right syntax.  I get duplicate column issues or missing column name issues.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to specify the table in the mapping like this?
http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/mapping.html

Comment: "I get duplicate column issues or missing column name issues" - Can you show the missing column name error message?

Answer (score 0):

The User in UserProfile would default to user_id which is the same as the id column for UserProfile.  So just add a column name for the user reference like below.

```
class UserProfile {
    Integer visitCount
    User user

    static mapping = {
        id column: 'user_id'
        user column: 'useruser_id'
    }
}

class User {
    String name

    static mapping = {
        id column: 'user_id'
    }

    static hasOne = [ userProfile: UserProfile ]
}
```

Comment: Is `userProfile column: 'userProfile_id'` required?

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: dommaping.UserProfile column: user_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
 at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:830)
 at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:848)
 at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:870)

Comment: Adding the column mapping to the user object did not help still got the above error.  Now added the column heading to the userProfile object and that resolved the issue.

Comment: "Now added the column heading to the userProfile object and that resolved the issue. " - That does not make sense to me.  The edit that you made to your answer does not have a column heading for `userProfile` (and shouldn't).

Comment: Why is it that you want both `UserProfile userProfile` and `static hasOne = [ userProfile: UserProfile ]` in the `User` class?

Comment: Good point I edited the answer with your correction. Thanks